# form validation for at least on select-option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

My form layout is similar to below:

```
<form action='' method="post" id='myform'>
    <select name='select1'>
        <option value=''>select option</select>
        <option value='a'> a </option>
        <option value='b'> b </option>
        <option value='c'> c </option>
    </select>
    <select name='select2'>
    <option value=''>select option</select>
    <option value='e'> e </option>
    <option value='f'> f </option>
    <option value='g'> g </option>
</select>
    <select name='select3'>
        <option value=''>select option</select>
        <option value='h'> h </option>
        <option value='i'> i </option>
        <option value='j'> j </option>
    </select>
</form>

<script> $('#myform').validate(); </script>
```

Note: I have included `jquery.js` and `jquery.validate.js` files.

Here, 3 select-option are in form. I need to validate at least one select-option only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function selectValidate() {
    var check = false;
    $.each($('select'), function(index, data) {
         if (data.val() !== ''){
              check = true;
         }
    });
    return check;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create your own validator method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("selectNone",  function(value, element) {if (element.value == " ") {return false;} else {return true};} ),
```

and then add in rules:

```
yourSelectID1: {required:true, selectNone:true},
yourSelectID2: {required:true, selectNone:true},
yourSelectID3: {required:true, selectNone:true},
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake on your html code. You should change each `<option value=''>select option</select>` to this `<option value=''>select option</option>`. So your html will be something like this: (I added the submit button to show the functionality)
**[jsFiddle Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/49DKt/2/)**


**HTML**

```
<form action='' method="post" id='myform' >
 <select name='select1' >
<option value=''>select option</option>
<option value='a'> a </option>
<option value='b'> b </option>
<option value='c'> c </option>
</select>
 <select name='select2' >
<option value=''>select option</option>
<option value='e'> e </option>
<option value='f'> f </option>
<option value='g'> g </option>
</select>
 <select name='select3' >
<option value=''>select option</option>
<option value='h'> h </option>
<option value='i'> i </option>
<option value='j'> j </option>
</select>
<input type='submit' value='validate '>
</form>
```

The main function is `validateSelects()`.
**JS**

```
function validateSelects()
{
    var m = false;
    $.each($('select'),function()
    {
         if( $(this).val() != ''){  m=true; }
    });
    return(m);
}
// For the functionality.
$('#myform').on('submit',function()
{
    return validateSelects(); 
});
```